# solutions to nonhomogeneous system of differential equations with general solution already known

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let's say we have the general solution to $X' = A(t)X$, where $X=(x_1, x_2)^T$.
How do you find the general solution to the system $X'= A(t)X + b(t)$
where $b(t)$ is a $2 \times 1$ matrix with two polynomials as entries. How do you find the particular solution?

Comment: I edited your question just a tad to fix a little grammar and spelling and make the math render *via* $\LaTeX$.  You might check out the mathjax tutorials.  Cheers!

Comment: Have you heard of the method of undetermined coefficients? I believe it is applicable in this case.

Comment: Or maybe variation of parameters, I always get these two methods confused.

Comment: @rajb245:  I can never keep them sorted out either!  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The *most* general solution to

$X' = A(t)X \tag{1}$

is the *fundamental matrix solution* $\Phi(t, t_0)$;  for any $t_0$͵ this is a time-dependent $2 \times 2$ matrix such that

$\Phi'(t, t_0) = A(t) \Phi(t, t_0) \tag{2}$

with

$\Phi(t_0, t_0) = I. \tag{3}$

Writing

$\Phi(t, t_0) = \begin{bmatrix} \phi_{11}(t, t_0) & \phi_{12}(t, t_0) \\ \phi_{21}(t, t_0) & \phi_{22}(t, t_0) \end{bmatrix}, \tag{4}$

we see that the colomns of $\Phi(t, t_0)$ are each themselves solutions of (1) with

$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{11}(t_0, t_0) \\ \phi_{21}(t_0, t_0) \end{pmatrix}   = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \tag{5}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} \phi_{12}(t_0, t_0) \\ \phi_{22}(t_0, t_0) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}. \tag{6}$

If

$X(t_0) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t_0) \\ x_2(t_0) \end{pmatrix} \tag{7}$

and we set

$X(t) = \Phi(t, t_0) X(t_0), \tag{8}$

then we see that

$X'(t) = \Phi'(t, t_0) X(t_0) = A(t) \Phi(t, t_0) X(t_0) = A(t) X(t) \tag{9}$

and

$X(t_0) = \Phi(t_0, t_0) X(t_0) = IX(t_0) = X(t_0); \tag{10}$

we see that (8) is the solution to (1)satisfying the initial condition (7).  The matrix $\Phi(t, t_0)$ is in fact possessed in linearly independent columns, since the same is true of its initial value $I$ (see (3)).  (This is a standard result which may be found in many texts covering the theory of linear systems.)  Thus we may regard $\Phi(t, t_0)$ as the most general solution of (1) possible;  by (8) any $2 \times 1$ vector solution $X(t)$ is expressible as a linear combination of the columns of $\Phi(t, t_0)$; since the solution space is two dimensional, it is *apropos* to regard $\Phi(t, t_0)$ as most general solution of (1).

If we have such a $\Phi(t, t_0)$ at our disposal, we may find an expression for the solution of the inhomogeneous equation

$X'(t) = A(t)X(t) + b(t) \tag{11}$

by means of $\Phi(t, t_0)$ as follows:  since the columns of the matrix $\Phi(t, t_0)$ are linearly independent, it is invertible and we have

$\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) \Phi(t, t_0) = I; \tag{12}$

differentiating (12) with respect to $t$:

$(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0))' \Phi(t, t_0) +  \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) \Phi'(t, t_0) = 0; \tag{13}$

using (2)

$(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0))' \Phi(t, t_0) +  \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0)  A(t)\Phi(t, t_0) = 0; \tag{14}$

right multiplying by $\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0)$ and isolating $(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0))'$:

$(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0))'  = -  \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0)  A(t). \tag{15}$

We use (15) together with (11) to evaluate $(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) X(t))'$, thusly:

$(\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) X(t))' = (\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0))' X(t) + \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) X'(t)$
$= -\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) A(t) X(t) + \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) (A(t) X(t) + b(t))$
$= -\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) A(t) X(t) + \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) A(t) X(t) + \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) b(t) = \Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) b(t); \tag{16}$

we may integrate (16) 'twixt $t_0$ and $t$:

$\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) X(t) - \Phi^{-1}(t_0, t_0) X(t_0)$
$= \int_{t_0}^t (\Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) X(s))' ds = \int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b(s) ds; \tag{17}$

*via* (3) we obtain

$\Phi^{-1}(t, t_0) X(t) = X(t_0) +  \int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b(s) ds, \tag{18}$

whence

$X(t) = \Phi(t, t_0)(X(t_0) +  \int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b(s) ds). \tag{19}$

Formula (19) presents the general solution to (11) in terms of the general solution $\Phi(t, t_0)$ of (1), as per request.  When $X(t_0) = 0$, we obtain the particular solution $X_p(t)$ associated with $b(t)$:

$X_p(t) = \Phi(t, t_0)\int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b(s) ds. \tag{20}$

We note that when $b(t) = 0$, (20) yields the solution to the homogeneous equation (1); the solutions to (1) are thus seen to accomodate the initial condtions, whereas $X_p(t)$ arises soley from the "driving" term $b(t)$.

We can't really say much more without solving (5) for $\Phi(t, t_0)$, and this can be quite difficult even for fairly simple $A(t)$; of course, in the event that $A(t)$ is *constant*, we may write

$\Phi(t, t_0) = e^{A(t - t_0)}͵ \tag{21}$

but this is one of the few cases in which a solution is known *a priori*.  In the event that the components of $b(t)$ are polynomials, we have

$b(t) = \sum_0^m t^i b_i, \tag{22}$
Tegral
where the $b_i$ are constant vectors; then the integral occurring in (19), (20) may be evaluated one power of $t$ at a time, *viz*

$\int_{t_0}^t \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b(s) ds = \sum_0^m \int_{t_0}^t s^i \Phi^{-1}(s, t_0) b_i ds, \tag{23}$

but this still doesn't get us very far for general $A(t)$, though in the case of constant $A(t)$ such integrals are found in many tables.

It is worth noting that virtually everything we have said generalizes beyond the $2 \times 2$ case to systems of arbitrary (finite) dimension.

The above technique is classical, and occurs in many textbooks.  I too think it is either the *variation of parameters* or *undetermined coefficients* method, but Iike my colleague in this question, rajb245, I can never remember which is which.

Phew!  Finally done!

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

And as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: The integral of $b$ against the fundamental solution immediately came to mind, but I had forgotten the details. Thanks for fleshing out that approach. The electrical engineer in me of course always calls this a "convolution", even if that integral kernel isn't shift-invariant.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the two solutions differently, and clean up notation. Lowercase boldface will denote vectors ($2\times1$). Plain uppercase will denote matrices. Plain lowercase will be scalars. All explicit dependence on $t$ will be dropped. Now the one without any forcing term on the right hand side is denoted with $\mathbf{x}$:

$$
\mathbf{x}' = A\mathbf{x}
$$

The one with forcing we'll denote by $\mathbf{y}$,
$$
\mathbf{y}' = A\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b}.
$$

Let's guess a form for $\mathbf{y}$. Let's guess it is the product of $\mathbf{x}$ and some unknown scalar function $u$,
$$
\mathbf{y} = u\mathbf{x}
$$
Then your equation becomes
$$
u\mathbf{x}'+u'\mathbf{x} = uA\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}
$$
But we already know that $\mathbf{x}'=A\mathbf{x}$ so substitute that
$$
uA\mathbf{x}+u'\mathbf{x} = uA\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}
$$
Canceling on both sides we are left with
$$
u'\mathbf{x} =  \mathbf{b}
$$
Multiplying by $\mathbf{x}^T$
$$
u'\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} =  \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}
$$
But $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}=||\mathbf{x}||^2$, so dividing by that scalar gives
$$
u' = \frac{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{b}}{||\mathbf{x}||^2},
$$
and integrating and putting back all the explicit $t$ dependence gives
$$
u(t) = \int\frac{\mathbf{x}^T(t)\mathbf{b}(t)}{||\mathbf{x}(t)||^2}dt
$$
If you take that and multiply this by your original known solution, then I think you have a particular solution $y$.

Comment: *Very well done*; innovative and informative; ***plus one!***  Never seen this argument before.  Cheers!

Comment: Note that ${\mathbf x} / \Vert \mathbf x \Vert$ is a unit vector in the $\mathbf x$ direction, so that ${\mathbf x}^T {\mathbf b} / \Vert \mathbf x \Vert$ is the projection of $\mathbf b$ in the $\mathbf x$ direction, leading to a nice geometrical interpretation!  Again I say, ***Well done!***